# Universal App not detecting iPad images

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, xcode4, image-scaling

I have an app which I'm converting to a universal binary.

The app uses a custom table view within a Tabbar controller which draws different sizes depending on the detected screenBound height.

It draws the table just fine on different devices but the rows in the table view use images as buttons.

image.png and image@2x.png work just fine but the app is failing to recognise image~ipad.png (have also tried image-ipad.png)

So no matter what I do the table is using iPhone images on iPad.

Have been trying for hours to figure out why. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the file case is correct? And the file was added not only to your project, but your target as well? If you are testing on a retina iPad, you should use image@2x~ipad.png.

Comment: Yup, case is correct. Targets confirmed and I've got the retina and standard in there as well just to make sure it's not defaulting to the iPhone @2x in the absence of @2x~ipad

Comment: Try deleting the app and doing a clean is first thing I'd do.

Comment: try to use the both "terminations" : MyImage~iphone.png / MyImage~ipad.png

Answer (score 1):

Check that your image is targeted to the app in Developer Tools. Select an image and then place a checkmark in Utility panel on the right